# Need help identifying a component from a dot-matrix display driver board

Tags: identification, dot-matrix-display

I was checking components of a dot-matrix driver circuit board and saw these components:

- AR31 "330"
- AR27 "330"

I tried searching for it online but got no good results. I found some similar package resistors, but I'm not sure whether this is it.

https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/yageo/YC358TJK-07330RL/1005325

If anyone has an idea what component this is, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [resistor arrays.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28751/acasprec.pdf)  Not necessarily the linked type, but something similar.

The ones in the linked datasheet are all separate - you can use each resistor independently.  Like this:

[image]

There are other styles where all of the resistors have a common connection like this:

[image]

You can get more resistors in the array for the same number of pins with the common pin type.

The common pin types are often used as pull ups for digital signals.

Answer (score 1):

Those are 33 ohm quad resistor packs.

AR27 and AR31 are just names or references to these components, in short, they are used for making a list which component should be mounted with what value componenent.

So both components called AR27 and AR31 are 33 ohm quad resistor packs.

Comment: AR probably stands for "Array of Resistors" in whatever language was native to the designer.